# Provisioning Web application toolkit

Tags: php, mysql, process, cpanel, provisioning

i created a web application for business products or services catalogue, for each selling i need to duplicate it and modify following my new customer information (obtained from form). is there a toolkit (better free) to automate this process? This is steps of the process:

1. Create a subdomain (i have a virtual server with Hostgator.com, cPanel and WHM)
2. Create mysql database
3. Copy and paste files and forlders in subdomain main folder
4. Modify php files or mysql fields

Tx for your help